# PubNub: Can I divide my users to groups and get messages only from one group on one channel?

Tags: pubnub

I have two types of users '*Managers*' and '*Students*' which subscribe to a channel '*all.channel*', I want the following behavior to be applied:

a. Users from 'Managers' group will get all messages published from both user groups '*Managers*' and '*Students*'.

b. Users from group 'Students' will get publish messages only from user of group 'Managers' (will not see 'Students' publish messages).

My idea was to create two channels:

a. '*all.channel*' - '*Managers*' and '*Students*' users will publish to it. only '*Managers*' users will subscribe to it. A pubnub 'After Publish' function will chain only 'Managers' message to another channel called '*all.student.channel*'

b. '*all.student.channel*' - only 'Students' will subscribe to it.

**My question is if there're any build-in tools or capabilities in PubNub to do it less complex, or even with only one channel?**

Comment: You can do this with one channel. However security is important to consider. Who can Send/Receive messages on that channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Manager & Student Configuration

> [Security is important](https://www.pubnub.com/products/security-overview/). Students should not see Manager's *private* messages.

You'll need to consider security.  Only `managers` should be able to see `manager` messages.  Consider multiplexing your channels for Managers.  A manager will subscribe to both `root.managers` channel and `root.students` channel too.  While `students` only subscribe to `root.students` channel. This way you can grant read/write permission to managers on the `root.*`. You can grant access to students on `root.students.roomID` to read/write.

> You may also consider  [ChatEngine](https://www.pubnub.com/products/chatengine/) an open and extensible chat SDK and APIs for building group chat.

More channel configuration options below for your consideration.

## Channel Configuration Options

For the PubNub SDKs 4.0 and higher.  Multiplexing the SDK supports up to about **50 channels practically**.  You can increase this number further but device performance will be impacted.  It is better to utilize the **Channel Group** feature of the core [PubNub Stream Controller](http://www.pubnub.com/products/stream-controller/) product.  Stream Controller includes the following channel subscription enhancements.

### Wildcard Subscribe

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( Unlimited )***

PubNub Also supports [Wildcard Subscriptions using a Hierarchical dot notation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#subscribe_example_wildcard).  Today in PubNub you can subscribe to channel **`"a.b.*"`** and receive messages at any channel below `a.b`.  You could publish to channel **`"a.b.c"`** and receive the message in your wildcard subscribe.  Note that the maximum depth supported of the hierarchy is currently a depth of **three**.  For example **`"a.b.*"`** is good but **`"a.b.c.*"`** is not supported.

### Channel Groups

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( 2,000 ✕ 10 ＝ 20,000 )***

Dynamically control the device's data stream feed with PubNub Channel Groups.  You can remotely control which streams the device is subscribed to and dynamically **add** and **remove** channels from the list of channels.  You can multiplex subscribe up to 10 channel groups and each channel group can contain up to 2,000 channels.

### Multiplexing

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( ~50 )***

You can multiplex your connection by subscribing to a combination of **Wildcard Channels**, **Channel Groups**, **Presence Event Stream Channels** and more.  It is recommended to keep your multiplexed channels below 50 for best device performance.

### Stream Filtering:

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( Unlimited )***

[Stream Filter](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-filtering-tutorial) allows a subscriber to apply a filter to only receive messages that satisfy the conditions of the filter. The message filter is set by the subscribing client(s) but it is applied on the server side thus preventing unwanted messages (those that do not meet the conditions of the filter) from reaching the subscriber. Stream Filters are implemented with two components: meta dictionary on publish and filter expression on subscribe. Filters are applied to all channels that the client is subscribed to. When messages are encrypted (using crypto key when initializing PubNub), the meta dictionary is plain text, so that the PubNub Network can properly apply the filters as required. It is important to only include information that is not confidential or otherwise requiring encryption.

Comment: Thanks! that helped. basically the student should subscribe to root.managers only. student should not see each other messages.